# Improve the Help page for creating a package

Tags: r

I created a package and in documentation i would like to know how to put letters ( -- A -- ) to represent the alphabetical order like this for ade4 package.

[image]

---

[Exemple package Hello World!](https://uptobox.com/z15zxztgoxs1)

Comment: How are you building the package, what stage is it at?

Comment: Hello, i create a _new project -> R package_ . I installed _devtools_, _roxygen2_  packages, then i did install_github("devtools", "hadley"). For build i click on _Build -> Install and Restart_. I edited my post to put an example of a package I created.  What do you mean by which stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything.  R will do that automatically once you have a large enough number of help topics.